# How to generate html markup based in json property value in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I got json (model property) like this:

```
[
{type:'a', val:'something'},
{type:'b', val:'something'}
]
```

Based on value of 'type', i need to render different html markup. I know i can accomplish it via ng-repeat and ng-if.

But wondering, if there is a better way of doing it, something like templating or such so code will be refractored and maintainable in long run?

Comment: this looks like a nice candidate for a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Thanks, it really looks cool and i can build upon provided example. In the meantime, i learned about ngInclude and ngView as well. To me, it looks like, any of three can serve my purpose.  Which one is best approach according to you, and why(if you can explain)?

Comment: exactly what you wrote: _code will be refractored and maintainable in long run_ - with directives you create reusable code/components and they can be tested. With angular, sooner or later you will come to directives, I'm sure.

Comment: Great! then sticking with directives... thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the research, I came across few alternatives which are listed below.

1. ngView
2. ngInclude
3. Angular Directives

For my requirement, I am sticking with directives instead.